# Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.mysite.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com"

Tags: django, heroku, zinnia

I've set up the zinnia blog app on my Django site on Heroku. I'm receiving this error in browser when on the zinnia wysiwyg editor: `Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.mysite.co.uk" from accessing a frame with origin "http://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com".`

Is there anyway round this? Seeing as I can't host the static zinnia files on Heroku I'm thinking im sod out of luck?